# 18.04.01 Not available for server

Tags: server, upgrade, lts

Ubuntu point release 18.04.01 is [out since yesterday](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/07/26/ubuntu-18-04-1-lts-released/). But when trying to update my 16.06 server nothing is not found, only the 18.04 is found when passing the dev option to the do-release-upgrade command:

```
[12:10:04] root:~# do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
No new release found.
[12:10:06] root:~# do-release-upgrade --check-dist-upgrade-only --dev
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
New release '18.04 LTS' available.
Run 'do-release-upgrade' to upgrade to it.
```

Am I missing something? Or it's just not available for now for servers?

Comment: Run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and try again.

Comment: They didn't commit the change to get it available, but you can upgrade with `-d` anytime.